# When is a cdf absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and $X$ be a random variable with distribution $\mu$. According to the theory developed in Section 3.5 of Folland's [Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160), $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure iff the cdf $F_X$ is absolutely continuous.

Assume that $F_X$ is known. What are tractable conditions on $F_X$ which guarantee that $F_X$ is absolutely continuous ?

For example, I know that the following condition is sufficient (since it implies that $F_X$ is Lipschitz):

> 1. $F_X$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$, $F_X$ is differentiable except perhaps at finitely many points, and $(F_X)'$ is bounded.

Are the following conditions also sufficient ?

> 2. $F_X$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$ and $F_X$ is differentiable except perhaps at finitely many points.

> 3. $F_X$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$ and $F_X$ is differentiable except perhaps at countably many points.

> 4. $F_X$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$ and $\int_{\mathbb R} F_X'(x) dx = 1$.

Note that $F_X$ already has some regularity (non-decreasing, cadlag, limits at $\pm \infty$, differentiable a.e.).

Comment: $F_X'$ has to be  integrable for absolute continuity to hold.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity for an overview.

Comment: I am very sure that condition #$3$ is sufficient, and I am pretty sure that the idea in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4294020/177399) is sufficient to prove it, but I am getting hung up on the details.

Comment: It is well known that any continuous cdf can be decomposed as $F = F_a + F_s$, where $F_a$ is absolutely continuous and $F_s$ has derivative $0$ almost everywhere. This implies that 2–4 are sufficient.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you, can you post this as answer ?

Comment: @Marloumarlou done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known (e.g. as a consequence of Lebesgue's decomposition theorem) that any continuous cdf can be decomposed as $F=F_a+F_s$, where $F_a$ is absolutely continuous and $F_s$ has derivative $0$ almost everywhere. This implies that 2–4 are sufficient.