# First fundamental theorem of Calculus continuity not necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I know if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $g(x) = \int _{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$. Furthermore, $g'(x) = f(x)$.

> This is known as the first fundamental theorem of Calculus. However, I wonder if the converse is true, that is when $g(x)$ is differentiable if $f(x)$ is necessarily continuous. I don't think this is the case, but neither can I conceive a counterexample.

I was thinking about this because I think even if the distribution of a random variable is differentiable, the density is not necessarily continuous.

---

I think as the comment said, we just need to change a continuous $f$ at one point so that it is no longer continuous, but $g$ is not changed. I'll link the following [somewhat unrelated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293703/does-a-random-variable-with-differentiable-distribution-function-have-density) for future reference.

Comment: No, $g'$ need not be continuous for example. Also, $f$ can be defined on a set of measure zero. However, if $g'$ is continuous, then $f$ must be essentially continuous.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus for Lebesgue integrals

Comment: If you just change the value of $f$ et some isolated points, the result will still be (Riemann-)integrable, and the integral $g$ will not have changed, but of course $f$ will fail to equal $g'$ at the points where we changed its value.

Comment: A trivial counterexample is if you take $f$ continuous, and define a new function $f_2$ which is equal to $f$ almost everywhere, but differs from $f$ on a finite or countable set of points. Then $f$ and $f_2$ have the same integral, but obviously $f_2$ is not continuous and $g'$ is not equal to $f_2$. The counterexample given in user146125 is stronger in the sense that it satisfies $g' = f$ even though $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: In general (removing the requirement $f(x)$ is continuous), you may find in some cases that $g(x)$ does not exist.  Even if $g(x)$ does exist, there may be values $x \in [a,b]$ where $g'(x) \not= f(x)$.  So you need some restriction on $f(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions $f(x)=-\cos(\frac1x) + 2 x \sin(\frac1x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, and $g(x)=x^2 \sin(\frac1x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$ are an example where this fails. $g(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)\; \mathrm{d}\,t$ and $g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2 \sin(\frac1x) -0}{x-0}=0=f(0)$ but $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.